# error while generating nifty:scaffold=> create_migration': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffold, nifty-gui

While am trying to create a scaffold 
rails g nifty:scaffold authentication user_id:integer provider:string uid:string index create destroy

authentication.rb was generated but no views
I am getting error as
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/nifty-generators-0.4.6/lib/generators/nifty/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:85:in `create_migration': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:63:in`migration_template'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/nifty-generators-0.4.6/lib/generators/nifty/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:87:in `create_migration'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`block in invoke_all'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`map'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in`dispatch'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in`invoke'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:135:in`generate_or_destroy'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in`run_command!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.2.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/user/Desktop/remake/bin/rails:8:in`'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`block in load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from -e:1:in `'

Answer (score 3):

Nifty generators havn't been updated since oct 2012 (from the github page). Use something different, because this gem is definitely not up-to-date.

Comment: which gem is better for authentication?
i want to use registrations of facebook and normal using omniauth and devise at same time

Comment: @user3710415 As you said devise and omniauth will suit your needs

Comment: i want to use both of them in same table

Comment: @user3710415 use devise to generate users table then create a migration to add uid, provider. For devise refer [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and for facebook example check [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

Comment: I want to save both registrations in same table
I am new to ror So could you please eloborate

Comment: @user3710415 I don't think it's a right place to elaborate on things. To give you a head start you'll have to install devise in your app and then `rails generate devise:install` `rails generate devise MODEL` and then follow the steps given in links. :) Try out things yourself that's how you'll learn and if you have any errors you can post them as questions. :)